# How to attach one debugger to two different IAR embedded workbench projects at the same time?

Tags: debugging, embedded, iar

I have two IAR projects, front_end.eww & back_end.eww. Both are compiled and flashed onto the same board. front_end takes the input from user and hand it over to back_end. I want to attach debugger and debug both the projects at the same time. I am using i-jet for debugging.

Comment: If the end system has a jtag chain, you must configure the correct ID for each project.

Comment: @LPs yes i have configured the correct project ID and there is one flag called "--jet_sigbrobe_opt=shared" which we need to pass as debugging configuration. i have tried the combination. It is still not working.

Comment: There is under Options...->Debugger-->I-jet->JTAG/SWD: Multi-target debug system. You should compile correctly its options and IDs. I never used I-jet, always j-link with vybrid SoC.

Comment: @LPs those options are disabled. how do i enable them ?

Comment: I don't know. As I wrote I never used I-jet. Sorry.

Comment: I would think, at a minimum, both projects (*.ewp) should be contained in the same IAR workspace (*.eww).  My experience is your debugger only has access to the symbols to correlate to c source and variables to one project at a time though you can still set break points and examine code with your debugger on the second project through the disassembler only.

Comment: Are both targets on the same board on the same JTAG chain?  (Or are there two separate jtag connectors going to two separate chips)?

Comment: @semaj you are right. If project has more than 1 module then we can debug through disassembler. But if you add module image ( debugger->image ) then we can set the breakpoints & debug code itself. We can see disassembler and source code side by side and trace the code flow. Actually i have seen people debugging two project simultaneously but i don't know how do they do it.

Comment: @RussSchultz yes both targets are on the same board on same JTAG.

Answer (score 0):

When you debug one application, you can load extra (ut to three) additional images (typically an ELF or UBROF file). You can either download the image to the device, or tell C-SPY to only read the related debug information.

See Options -> Debugger -> Images -> Download extra image

Comment: i have added extra image. After attaching debugger to one project when i try to attach 2nd project a window popup showing fatal error and reason for it is Specified probe is not available.

Comment: The idea is that you should only use one debugger, as it downloads both its own and the other applications image to the device.

Comment: i am using one board and one debugger. I have two images flashed onto board. Each image has it's own IAR project. In order to debug both the project either i can attach debugger to one project at a time or do some settings to share my debugger among two IAR projects. for sharing debugger i have added both the images in Download extra image option, added " --jet_sigprobe_opt=shared " in debugger -> extra options, selected correct CPU in i-jet/jtag -> JTAG/SWD option. after doing all this i expected it to work but still it's not working.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know the details about how the IJet work. I suggest that you contact the IAR support department.